# While running "n=n++", it outputs the original value of 'n'

Tags: c++

```
int n = 1;
n = n++;
cout<<n<<endl;

output:1
```

I have searched it on Google. Analysis says that `"n = n++" is:First assign n to n, then n add 1.`

I don't know why it is giving output as 1, rather than 2.

Comment: The code suggests C++ but you also have tags for Java and C.  It matters which one it is.  So which is it?

Comment: I have removed the Java and C tags, because this code snippet is clearly C++.

Comment: A possible expansion is `int tmp = n; n++; n = tmp;` which yields 1. However, as others have commented, the expansion is ambiguous, since it could have been `int tmp = n; n = tmp; n++; ` which would have yielded what you wanted to see. Either expansion is possible, which is why it's best not to write such ambiguous code.

Comment: Definitely C++. In C++: `n += 1;`, ‘n++;` and `++n` all increment `n` by one. I think that’s what you’re trying to do. Work on your question quality!

Answer (score 2):

This code is undefined behavior. The compiler can do anything, even make demons fly out of your nose if it feels like it. To find out more about this, you can read up at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Comment: Where can I buy a compiler that can make demons fly out of my nose?

Comment: I bet you can find one at nullptr @DawoodibnKareem

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem to see the name , go `cout << string(0);`

Comment: @M.M I tried it.  I now have a sore nose, and there's this little red guy with horns and a pitchfork sitting on my keyboard.  Help!